# Super linter : Terrascan s3 bucket issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, acl, super-linter

I am facing the issue while adding super linter in the git actions for my terraform files.

The terrascan present in the super linter is giving the following error

> results:
> violations:
>
> - rule_name: s3EnforceUserACL                                                                                                                                                 description: S3 bucket Access is allowed to all AWS Account Users.
>   rule_id: AWS.S3Bucket.DS.High.1043
>   severity: HIGH
>   category: S3
>   resource_name: <resource_name>
>   resource_type: aws_s3_bucket
>   file: main.tf
>   line: 38
>   count:
>   low: 0
>   medium: 0
>   high: 1
>   total: 1

My terraform code for this s3 is

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket        = <BUCKER_NAME>
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = true
  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "bucket_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}
```

Not getting any details for the error on the terrascan documents.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: What version of `terrascan` are you using?

Comment: In my git -ction the super linter is using 1.2 but on my local, I tried with v1.3.2 and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the Bucket Policy, either by:

- `aws_s3_bucket.policy` parameter (so-called inline policy, note that this will [skip the whole policy analysis](https://github.com/accurics/terrascan/blob/1027346ee6fb13c123e3695c34f5ef7c0fc815e9/pkg/policies/opa/rego/aws/aws_s3_bucket/s3EnforceUserACL.rego#L7))
- `aws_s3_bucket_policy` dedicated resource

Reference: [s3EnforceUserACL.rego](https://github.com/accurics/terrascan/blob/1027346ee6fb13c123e3695c34f5ef7c0fc815e9/pkg/policies/opa/rego/aws/aws_s3_bucket/s3EnforceUserACL.rego)